# Set cookie for a specific domain in PHPCrawl

Tags: php, cookies, phpcrawl

I use [PHPCrawl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcrawl/) for crawl websites but now I want to add a cookie to specific domain, because this domain has a authentication and I want to get information in authorized pages.

How can I add a cookie to specific domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find a way to add cookie to an specific domain:

I going to overload __construct in my own crawler class like this:

```
class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler 
{
    function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();

        $s = new PHPCrawlerCookieDescriptor("localhost", "JSESSIONID", "DE7BCB89B0D5BB072357450F01415FAB");
        $f[] = $s;
        $this->PageRequest->addCookieDescriptors($f);
    }
}
```

Now you should have a cookie with `JSESSIONID` name and `DE7BCB89B0D5BB072357450F01415FAB` for it's value.